# What's the difference between time() and Date.now()

Tags: javascript, php

I have this value with PHP time() : 1454346117

And in same time with JavaScript Date.now() : 1454346117299

As you see in JavaScript i have 3 more digit in last. How to fix that i need 
same number?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in javascript:

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
```

to get the same format

Answer (score 9):

[PHP: `time`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

> Returns the current time measured in the number of **seconds** since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

[Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

> [R]eturns the number of **milliseconds** elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

To get seconds from miliseconds on javascript just divide by 1000, like this:

```
var seconds = new Date() / 1000;
```